# How large of a cardinal can $2^{\aleph_0}$ be?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

From what I understand, it's independent of ZFC whether $2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_\alpha$ for any nonzero ordinal $\alpha$. But there are larger cardinalities than the $\aleph$ numbers, especially if we start including large cardinal axioms. So my question is twofold.

1. Can ZFC alone prove the existence of a cardinal $\kappa$ such that $2^{\aleph_0} \le \kappa$?
2. Do any of the large cardinal axioms together with ZFC imply the existence of a $\kappa$ with $2^{\aleph_0} \le \kappa$?

Comment: Under $\mathsf{ZFC}$ every infinite cardinal is an $\aleph_\alpha$ for some ordinal $\alpha$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh. Well I guess that answers the first question. Follow-up: Can ZFC prove there exists $\alpha$ such that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_\alpha$, even if it can't prove which one?

Comment: @eyeballfrog: Yes: ZFC proves that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is an infinite cardinal, _and_ ZFC proves that every infinite cardinal is $\aleph_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog That's a consequence of what he said. Under ZFC, *every set is in bijection with an $\aleph_\alpha$.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The axiom of choice is equivalent to stating that every infinite cardinal is an $\aleph$ number. We can talk about non-$\aleph$ cardinals in the absence of choice, but it's still true there is a proper class of $\aleph$ cardinals, regardless of assuming choice or not.

The continuum, therefore, is certainly an $\aleph$ number under $\sf ZFC$, and since we cannot prove that $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ or not, there is no ordinal that $\sf ZFC$ *proves* is the $\aleph_\alpha$ of the continuum. What $\sf ZFC$ does prove is that *if* $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_\alpha$, then $\alpha>0$ and $\operatorname{cf}(\alpha)>\aleph_0$; and we know that this is the *only* provable restriction on the size of the continuum from the works of Cohen and Solovay.

To recap: assuming $\sf ZFC$, the continuum is an $\aleph$ cardinal.

Large cardinal axioms do postulate the existence of "large cardinals", but this is a technical term—without a well-defined meaning—and not a term for a cardinal larger than all the $\aleph$'s. It is just usually the case that if $\kappa$ is a large cardinal, then $\kappa=\aleph_\kappa$ (not always, though!) so it is sort of hard to describe $\kappa$ using the $\aleph$ numbers.

Moreover, due to the work of Levy and Solovay, we also know that *most* large cardinal axioms are compatible with both the continuum hypothesis and its negation, so large cardinals do not determine the value of the continuum either.

Comment: Do I remember correctly that $\kappa=\aleph_\kappa$ can even happen below the continuum?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sure - start with a ground model $V$, and consider $\kappa\in V$ with $V\models \kappa=\aleph_\kappa$; now add $\kappa^+$-many Cohen reals. This forcing is c.c.c., so preserves cardinals, so $\kappa=\aleph_\kappa$ continues to hold in $V[G]$; but $V[G]$ also satisfies $2^{\aleph_0}>\kappa$. Essentially, the point is that since the statement "$\kappa=\aleph_\kappa$" doesn't involve exponentiation, if it can happen at all then it can happen below $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @Henning: Yes, the $\alpha\mapsto\aleph_\alpha$ is continuous, so it has a closed and unbounded class of fixed points. Using what Noah suggested we can even arrange that $2^{\aleph_0}$ is a fixed point, simply requiring that the cofinality of the chosen number of generic reals is uncountable.

Comment: I'd be happy to hear about the downvote!